# Beach tennis rackets with most control?

Tags: tennis, racket, beach-tennis

I am trying to keep my tennis level high. 
Sometimes, I do not find any field to play tennis in Riga. 
So I think the good thing is to play beach tennis on badminton fields. 
I have now tested about 5 rackets of the brands King and MBT. 
I will post here soon the specific rackets which I have tested.

**Which are the beach tennis rackets with most control?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each racket is distinguished by the following characteristics:

- weight
- balance
- hardness

> **Weight**
>   A lighter racquet allows greater ease and speed of movement. However, for hitting the shots, a light racquet requires greater effort on the the arm. Otherwise, a heavier racquet offers more power on the ball, without affecting the arm as much as a light racquet. A good choice should be to choose the racket with the maximum weight the player can manage.
>
> **Balancing**
>   The more the racket is balanced on his head, the more this will promote the power of the shot (think especially smash and service). Nevertheless, this type of racket bears more intensely on the wrist. A balanced racquet towards the handle, however, allows a very accurate control of the ball and easier on the wrist.
>
> **Hardness of the frame**
>   A racquet with a more elastic frame favors the offensive game, giving more power to the shots and the best defense on smash. However, a stiffer racquet is characterized by a better control of the ball and more accurate hit. Moreover, the choice of the racket frame, it should also be considered the type of ball to be used: if the ball is hard, we advise you to use a rigid plate. Conversely, if the ball is soft or as much used, we recommend using a softer racquet.

**The racket should be chosen thinking of the characteristics of the player**